# Functions which invoke @Composable functions must be marked with the @Composable annotation

Tags: android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-text

Below is my Code while build the code i getting this error

Functions which invoke @Composable functions must be marked with the @Composable annotation

@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function

@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function

Showing Error at

```
@Composable
public fun MessageCard(msg: Message) {
    Text(text = msg.author)
    Text(text = msg.body)
}
```

Complete Code

````
class LayoutList : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            MessageCard(Message("Android", "Jetpack Compose"))
        }
    }
}


@Composable
public fun MessageCard(msg: Message) {
    Text(text = msg.author)
    Text(text = msg.body)
}


@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewMessageCard() {
    MessageCard(
        msg = Message("Colleague", "Hey, take a look at Jetpack Compose, it's great!")
    )
}

data class Message(val author: String, val body: String)```
````

Answer (score 0):

As every composable function should be called from another composable function.
Please see this solution for your understanding and hope will work for you,

[Jetpack compose AppBarIcon complains that "Functions which invoke @Composable functions must be marked with the @Composable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59807648/jetpack-compose-appbaricon-complains-that-functions-which-invoke-composable-fu)